# Which design pattern should I use if I have to go through a series of predefined steps and there are different options available in each step?

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, architecture, system-design

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to decide which path to take in the code based on the request data. In the request are e.g. attributes like business process, which I always want to query and based on that I decide what kind of response will be built later.

- I thought about using a *Strategy pattern* in combination with a *Builder pattern*.
- On the other hand, a *Chain of Responsibility* with a *Strategy Pattern* would also make sense in my eyes.

[image: Idea of what i want to achieve]

Comment: Should these `AttributeIs{XYZ Color}Object` run in parallel? Or based on the the output of the `Color Attribute Desider` should only one be executed?

Comment: It should be based on the output

Comment: I think you should look for the middleware pattern which is an [*application pipeline to handle requests and responses*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-7.0). In other words the chain of responsibility + strategy patterns combo would be fine.